# Using QuaZip to extract .cbz and create QImages in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qimage, quazip

I am currently trying to unzip a .cbz file (basically a .zip file) and store all of the .png images contained in that .cbz file to a `std::vector<QImage>`.

I am using QuaZip to do this.  I've looked at a few examples online and have tried implementing a few different methods using QuaZip classes documentation.

This is the code that I currently have:

```cpp
// Store all files for later access given the CBZ file
bool CbzReader::loadCbzFile(QString cbzFile) {
    QuaZip zip(cbzFile);
    zip.open(QuaZip::mdUnzip);

    const QStringList fileList = zip.getFileNamesList();
    QStringList allFiles = JlCompress::extractFiles(cbzFile, fileList);

    QImage newImage;
    for(int file = 0; file < fileList.size(); file++) {
        QImageReader reader(allFiles[file]);
        newImage = reader.read();

        if(newImage.isNull()) return false;

        imageList.push_back(newImage); //save image to class variable    
    }

    return true;
}
```

The variable `allFiles` contains 265 entries, however, inside of the for loop, it is returning `false`, as the `newImage` is said to be `invalid` by Qt.

What about this am I doing incorrectly?  Should I use different functions within QuaZip instead of JlCompress?

Comment: Maybe your path is wrong. Also check your current working directory for the extracted images. See if they are readable with imaging software.

Comment: You could add a quick check using [QFile::exists(allFiles\[file\])](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#exists) to make sure the extracted file actually exists before trying to read it.

Comment: @drescherjm The path to the .cbz file?  No, I think it is correct.  The `fileList` list does contain the files within the original .cbz file.  However, the .cbz file contains a mixture of both .jpeg and .png images after inspecting it further.  Perhaps this is the issue?

Comment: I am talking about if there was any folder structure in the compressed file.

Comment: @G.M. I tried that out, and yes, it does exist.

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions.  It turns out that uncompressing the .cbz file resulted in at least one file that was not a .png or .jpg, so now I perform file extension checks to make sure the extension is correct and everything is working properly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that extracting the .cbz file resulted in at least one file that was not an image file, and a QImage was attempting to be made out of this, causing an error.  I was not paying close enough attention to the contents of the unzipped file.

This now works since I'm using a boolean expression to check the file extensions of the uncompressed files.

So yeahhhh, my bad guys.